# How can I integrate $\frac{\sin x \cdot e^{\tan x}}{\cos^3 x}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

How can I calculate this integral? How do I get rid of $e^{\tan x}$?

$$\int \frac{\sin x \cdot e^{\tan x}}{\cos^3 x} \,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Try a substitution $t = \tan x$. What is $\mathrm dt/\mathrm dx$?

Comment: (Here is a good rule of thumb for integrals: when you run into a complex function of which you know how to integrate the "outside", try to perform a substituion on the "inside". Here, you didn't know how to deal with $e^{\tan x}$, but you can definitely deal with $e^t$, so $t=\tan x$ is a good choice.)

Comment: It would be more interesting to calculate the integral as it first appeared, i.e. with cosine squared in the denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a more clear form your integrand is
$$
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\mathrm{e}^{\tan x}\sec^2 x dx 
$$
Then making the sub $t =\tan x\to dt = \sec^2 x dx$ we find
$$
t \mathrm{e}^t dt 
$$
Which is easier.